# SSLConfig().relaxedHTTPSValidation() is not skipping certificates validations for RestAssured Test cases

Tags: tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, rest-assured

SSL is not getting ignored on Tomcat server while running RestAssured test cases.
I have setup SSL (certificate authentication) on tomcat server. Also done the setup to auto switch from HTTP to HTTPS.
Rest assured test cases are not working on "Auto Http to https enabled server" whereas those are working on SSL enabled server which does not have auto redirection from http top https.
I have tried with below solutions

```
RestAssured.given().config(RestAssured.config().sslConfig( new SSLConfig().relaxedHTTPSValidation()))

RestAssured.given().relaxedHTTPSValidation("TLS")

RestAssured.given().relaxedHTTPSValidation()
```

But nothing is working and I am getting the error:-

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
```

Even I tried giving full URL as HTTPS like below but got the same error

```
    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://localhost:8443/some/rest/";
    RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
    RestAssured.given().when().get("role/listAll").then().statusCode(200);
```

I do not want to set up key-store and use it for test cases instead I want to skip all https and SSL validations while running rest assured test case.

Thanks in advance!!